# Why do we need blind or buried vias in our layout? What is the difference from micro vias?

Tags: pcb-design, via

I have a 6-layer board with blind vias from 2-3-4-5 and micro vias (size: 0.004").

While it isn't a high density circuit with conductor width 6 mil and pads 0.02").

Can anybody share some tips on these? Why do we need to put blind vias in our design? What function it will achieve?

Answer (score 6):

Blind and buried vias are very expensive in production, and are not much used. The advantage over common vias is that they allow for more densely populated boards, since the buried vias don't need space on the component layers.
Microvias can be through-hole or blind or buried, they are just small diameter holes which are laser drilled instead of mechanically.

Comment: Stevenvh,do you know how much it will increase than normal vias boards, Suppose it has buried 2-5,blined vias 1-2.5-6,Min Tracking width/sPacing:4mil,min laser drill:4 mil

Comment: @NancyZhang - completely depends on your board's layout and the kind of packages you use. Big BGAs will have a grid of vias between the balls, and with through-hole vias it will be impossible to place certain parts on the other side, like other BGAs.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Stevenvh,Refer to bare boad cost,may be we need to ask fabricator directly. All we know buried vias will increase the difficulty of manufacturing process.so the price is much higher than normal board. Any one who have experiences on the board .welcome your comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ask then most likely you do not need to put blind vias. Blind vias enable more dense part layout because you do need to avoid blind vias on the other side of the board.